# Qual o nome do traje da foto?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, vocabulário

Estou precisando descrever a roupa de um determinado personagem de uma foto, mas das diversas buscas que fiz não obtive sucesso.

[image]

A primeira coisa que lembrei quando vi a imagem foi da roupa que o Shiryu (de Cavaleiros do Zodíaco [en-US: Saint Seiya]) usa quando não está trajando a armadura. Mas não consegui nada, fosse nas Wikias, que normalmente tem tudo e mais um pouco, tanto em português quanto em inglês, além de buscas **bastante** filtradas no Google, mas tudo que eu obtive como resultado foram sites de venda de bonecos e camisetas.

Minha irmã disse ser um kimono masculino e, fazendo uma Pesquisa por Imagem, de fato, o Google até retornou vários kimonos, a maioria de Cosplay da Yūki Konno de Sword Art Online, o que nem chega perto porque esse, na minha ignorância, meio que parece misturado com uma roupa de mestre de picadeiro (de circo). Além disso, pesquisas manuais sobre modelos de kimono, formais ou informais, se é que existe tal distinção, também não deram em nada.

Além do nome geral da vestimenta, se possível e/ou justificável, seria interessante saber o nome dessa peça azul, parecendo uma "língua", visível na altura da cintura, e se essas abotoaduras diferentes no peito têm algum nome específico.

Comment: A língua azul poderia ser um tabardo por baixo já que vai até o pescoço.

Comment: Essa foto mostra uma mistura de uniforme militar com um estilo de roupa não militar por causa das mangas. Essas mangas evasê nunca se veem roupas militares. Eu diria: casaco com torçal e mangas evasé [a partir dos cotovelos]. Não penso que exista uma só palavra....é bem romance gráfico. O kimono é japonês e essa peça não apresenta nenhuma das características de um kimono.....

Comment: A parte que desce parece como a ponta de uma estola, como vestem os padres católicos e outros.

Comment: correção: em roupas militares. Não entendo preguntas que depois são "abandonadas". A fechadura no peito pode ser descrita como torçal: Cordão de fios de retrós.

Comment: A pergunta não foi abandonada, eu só não iria ficar parado dando F5 a cada hora, afinal, eu precisava escrever o artigo no qual essa roupa seria mencionada em, digamos, apenas um parágrafo. Mas enfim, em meio a muitos resultados nada a ver, eu vi uma foto de roupas de estilo (não sei se é bem um estilo) **T’ai chi ch’üan**. E com pesquisas reversas dessa foto vi outras que combinaram bem o formato geral e os "botões". Ficou faltando apenas as mangas enormes e a "cauda" que parece um fraque. Até poder bater o martelo com aquilo que realmente é, descrevi assim com bastante liberdade artística.

Comment: Bruno, podes adicionar uma (auto-)resposta com essa maneira que encontraste de descrever. :)

Comment: Eu chamaria essa peça de roupa de "gibão".

Comment: Esse estilo vem de ***um desenho animado***. Não existe em si. Eis o t'ai chi ch'uan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tai_chi Essas mangas se chaman evasê do francês. A próxima vez não vou perder meu tempo. Nenhum dos vestuários (trajes) nas fotos tem a ver com essa sua "foto". É um desenho.

Comment: É claro que é de um desenho! Está nítido nos traços que foram criado por um artista para alguma empresa licenciadora de informes publicitários, animações, comerciais, produtos físicos e muito mais. O artista se baseou em alguma coisa que existe no mundo real (camisetas, jalecos, tangas, togas, aliens, dragões, florestas, parques... já vi de tudo enquanto escrevia). Se perdeu seu tempo foi porque se dispôs a (não) ajudar e, fosse comigo ou com outra pessoa, em outro tópico, estaria "perdendo tempo" de todo o jeito, afinal, você com certeza não está ganhando nada pra responder nada por aqui.

Comment: Obrigado por deletarem meu comentário complementar ao anterior. O cidadão ali pode se achar dodói e sair batendo o pézinho que tá tudo bem.

Answer (score 2):

O traje certamente tem origem militar, porém com aspecto estilizado, demonstrando uma derivação de sua origem. As cores azul e dourado / amarelo foram tradicionalmente utilizadas em uniformes militares de diferentes regiões no século 18 e 19 (como por exemplo no uniforme de D. Pedro II e Napoleão, e na indumentária do exército real português) entretanto esse modelo acabou se tornando comum em muitas vertentes  de representação artística/estilizada, inclusive nas mesmas cores tradicionais azul-amarelo/dourado.

Considerando tratar-se de uma derivação (já que as mangas largas desvirtuam o uso militar) temos varios exemplos semelhantes, como no movimento steampunk, ou seja, retrofuturismo, que utiliza muito casacos assim.

Por seu comprimento alongado, e o fato de se usar sobre outras peças, é classificado como casaco (e não como jaqueta). Logo, entendo ser sem dúvida um “casaco militar”, ou “casaco pseudo militar” ou “casaco de inspiraçao militar”, mas devido a ser um modelo bastante genérico e comum, não se pode situar em nenhum local ou uso específico.

[image]